# How to split up remaining height between two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, layout

This is a fairly common problem to which I have yet to find an elegant solution:

I have a couple of block elements (let's say 4) in a div. A very simple vertical layout.

The first two elements have fixed heights. The remaining two elements should split up the remaining space (i.e. body-height - first-element-height - second-element-height).

I know I can just calculate the sizes, but is there an elegant way to achieve this?

I'd like a solution that uses either native browser features (it's an internal app only running on modern Firefox/Chrome versions, so bleeding edge is OK) or jQuery/jQuery UI (we already use it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS3 flexbox layout: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

Comment: I've scanned the spec but can't see how to solve my problem with flexbox. Care to hack an example together?

Comment: @futlib: the link I gave has the exact thing you're asking for as an example (albeit with `box-orient:horizontal` and only 1 and not 2 fixed-height elements).

Comment: Thanks, that does it! I ignored that article because it said it was outdated and went for the spec (which also allows that, after some more investigation). But adding vendor prefixes to the examples in that article make it work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery for calculating the height.

suppose we have:

```
<div id="parent" style="height:300px; background-color: red;">
    <div id="first" style="height:100px; background-color: blue;">
    </div>
    <div id="second" style="height:100px;  background-color: #c6c6c6;">
    </div>

    <div id="third" style="background-color: #75ac19;" ></div>
    <div id="fourth" style="background-color: black;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var parrentHeight= $("#parent").height();
  var firstBlock = $("#first").height();
  var secondBlock = $("#second").height();
  var remainingHeight = parrentHeight - (firstBlock + secondBlock);
  $("#third, #fourth").height(remainingHeight / 2);
</script>
```

Comment: That's how I've always done it, I'm looking for modern alternatives.

Comment: unfortunately there is no method for this very specific styling, you can write a javascript function which fulfill the task, by passing parameters to it.

Answer (score 0):

Play around with percantage value xx(%) and not xx(px) for the height and width.